# python-docx: Extracting text along with heading and sub-heading numbers

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I have a word document that is structured as follows:

```
1. Heading
    1.1. Sub-heading
        (a) Sub-sub-heading
```

When I load the document in `docx` using the code:

```
import docx

def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)
print(getText("a.docx"))
```

I get the following output.

```
Heading
Sub-heading
Sub-sub-heading
```

How can I extract the heading/sub-heading numbers also along with the text? I tried [simplify_docx](https://github.com/microsoft/Simplify-Docx) but that only works for standard MS Word heading styles and not on custom heading styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately numbers are not part of the text but are generated by Word itself based on the heading style (`Heading i`), and I don't thing `docx` exposes any way to get this number.

However you can retrieve the style / level using `para.style` and then read through the document to recompute the numbering scheme. This is however cumbersome as it doesn't take into account any custom style you could be using. There might be a way to access the numbering scheme in the `style.xml` part of the doc but I don't know how.

```py
import docx

level_from_style_name = {f'Heading {i}': i for i in range(10)}

def format_levels(cur_lev):
    levs = [str(l) for l in cur_lev if l != 0]
    return '.'.join(levs)  # Customize your format here

d = docx.Document('my_doc.docx')

current_levels = [0] * 10
full_text = []

for p in d.paragraphs:
    if p.style.name not in level_from_style_name:
        full_text.append(p.text)
    else:
        level = level_from_style_name[p.style.name]
        current_levels[level] += 1
        for l in range(level + 1, 10):
            current_levels[l] = 0
        full_text.append(format_levels(current_levels) + ' ' + p.text)

for l in full_text:
    print(l)
```

which from

[image]

gives me

```py
Hello world
1 H1 foo
1.1 H2 bar
1.1.1 H3 baz
Paragraph are really nice !
1.1.2 H3 bibou
Something else
2 H1 foofoo
You got the drill…
```

Comment: Works like a charm. For any future readers,  'level_from_style_name' dictionary could be modified with your custom styles and their respective levels.